# Is compressive sensing a type of interpolation?

Tags: numerical-methods, signal-processing, numerical-optimization

In what ways is compressive sensing different from traditional numerical interpolation of sampled points from a given signal?

Comment: In compressed sensing the measurements are random projections of the signal that we want to recover. In traditional numerical interpolation, we are given measurements of the signal itself. In compressed sensing, we know that the signal we want to recover is sparse, and the strategy is to find a sparse signal which is consistent with the given measurements. In traditional interpolation, sparsity plays no role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "traditional" compressive sensing (CS) considers the problem of recovering *exactly* an unknown vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ from $m<N$ *linear* observations, i.e., from a vector $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times N}$ is a, so called, sensing matrix (which is known). As the resulting system of linear equations is underdetermined, CS makes the additional assumption that $\mathbf{x}$ has only $s \ll N$ non-zero elements when expressed with respect to a certain (known) basis, i.e., $\mathbf{x}$ is *sparse*. CS theory investigates what properties $\mathbf{A}$ should have in order to recover $\mathbf{x}$  with the smallest possible number of observations $m$, as well as  designing practical (numerical) algorithms to do that.

Interpolation is usually considered as the problem of recovering an unknown vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ by *directly* observing only $m<N$ of its elements. Since, as stated, this problem is ill posed, common interpolation methods such as linear, cubic or spline make the additional assumption that the values of consecutive elements of $\mathbf{x}$ are not significantly different, i.e., $\mathbf{x}$ is "smooth". In general, conventional interpolation does not guarantee exact recovery of the unknown vector. A notable exception are bandlimited signals, which can indeed be recovered exactly under a sampling scheme with periodic samples, taken with sufficiently large (Nyquist) frequency.

Therefore, the major differneces of CS and conventional interpolation are

1. *Observation model*: CS considers a more general observation model than conventional interpolation
2. *Unknown vector assumptions*: CS considers the recovery of sparse vectors (w.r.t. some basis) whereas interpolation considers "smooth"/"bandlimited" vectors. Note that, in general, a sparse vector is not "smooth"/"bandlimited" and vice versa.
3. *Theoretical analysis*: CS provides rigorous guarantees for the exact recovery of sparse vectors, whereas few things can be said on the exact recovery of signals by numerical interpolation.

Comment: Awesome explanation thanks for the comment